# Несоответствие типов данных C#: datetimepicker и "дата и время" Access

Tags: c#, visual-studio

День добрый!

Имеется элемент управления "datetimepicker" в Visual C# и база Access

С помощью форм, пользователь выбирает дату, в итоге получается вот такой запрос.

```
select * from Валюта where [Дата начала торгов] = '06.04.2018'
```

***(этот запрос скопирован из значения строки запроса в рантайме)***

[image: Скрин из конструктора таблицы]

В коде, принудительно конвертирую дату, в тот формат, который имеется в access (скрин бд выше).

Вот код конвертации

```
string sql = "select * from Валюта where [Дата начала торгов] = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "'";
```

В итоге я ловлю такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Уже второй день воюю. Буду благодарен любым ответам.**

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что дата в БД хранится в специальном формате и "формат вывода" ее в формы никак на это не влияет?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что мне грубо говоря необходимо сравнить эти даты. Как сравнить эти типы?

Comment: Просто используйте параметризированные запросы, все остальное за вас сделает библиотека. Чтобы можно было ответить конкретным примером, необходима информация о том, какую библиотеку используете.

Comment: так вы не склеивайте sql запрос, а используйте вместо этого параметризированные запросы